# Why can I make a type with a string value but can't reference a const?

Tags: typescript

I can do:

```
type ValidKeys = 'a' | 'b';
```

but I can't do:

```
const keyA = 'a';
const keyB = 'b';
type ValidKeys = keyA | keyB;
```

> 'keyA' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you
> mean 'typeof keyA'?

Why is this? I need to make use of references to `keyA` and `keyB` throughout my code, and do not want to have to have duplicate strings.

Comment: Because it's a value, not a type. _Did_ you mean `typeof keyA`?

Comment: You mean  `type keyA = 'a'; type keyB = 'b' type ValidKeys = keyA | keyB;`

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe is right; this will work:

```
const keyA = 'a';
const keyB = 'b';
type ValidKeys = typeof  keyA | typeof keyB;

const x: ValidKeys = 'a';
const y: ValidKeys = 'b';
const z: ValidKeys = 'c'; // Type error!
```

However, you may also want to do away with the keyA and keyB variables entirely and just use 'a' and 'b' directly. As long as your code is well-typed, the compiler will catch you if you accidentally write something other than 'a' or 'b' so there isn't really a need for the variables.

Comment: Wow.. that's so not intuitive.  I would have thought `typeof keyA | typeof keyB` would result in `string | string` and thus that would not accomplish anything.

Comment: @patrick if they were both `string`-typed, e.g. if they were `let`s, it would (well, you'd get `string` - `string | string` is redundant). But because they're `const`s, the inferred types are the string literal types `'a'` and `'b'`, hence `typeof  keyA | typeof keyB` -> `'a' | 'b'`.